# delete from the database monthly

Tags: mysql

I have this mysql command i am trying to delete rows in a database table from by year but the server crashes and mysql is doing a rollback after this happens.

How can i make this work to delete months seperatly ? for example if i want to delete all of 2019/11 and 2011/11 in 2 separate execustions and not the whole year of 2019 in one go? each year is about 1.000.000 rows?

the row dt is in the format of "2019-08-13 10:36:11"

```
DELETE FROM sptfy_sptfy.stats WHERE dt < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a practical limit on the size of a transaction in MySQL. How people get around this is to run a series of deletions with a more modest number of rows.

```
DELETE FROM sptfy_sptfy.stats WHERE dt < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR LIMIT 1000;
```

You can keep running that statement over and over and checking the number of rows affected by the delete. Eventually you'll try a batch and it will report zero rows affected, and then you're done (until next month).

You can experiment to see if you can use larger batch sizes if you want, but why bother?

Answer (score 1):

`PARTITION` the table by months, using `PARTITION ... BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(...))`  Then `DROP PARTITION` once a month; it is *very* fast for any sized table.

More:  [*Partition*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)

Answer (score 0):

Deleting big batches of rows is often a Bad Idea.
Far better to "nibble" away at the data in smaller chunks.

If you data goes back many years and you want to get "back" to just one year being stored (as, I assume, defined by your Data Retention Policy) then start by deleting [a small amount of] the very, very oldest data:

```
DELETE FROM sptfy_sptfy.stats 
WHERE dt < NOW() - INTERVAL 4000 DAYS ;
```

Assuming that `dt` has a suitable index on it, that shouldn't cause much of a "splash" in your database.
Then, run the same thing again, but bringing the deletion "window" a little bit closer to where it needs to be:

```
DELETE FROM sptfy_sptfy.stats 
WHERE dt < NOW() - INTERVAL 3999 DAYS ;
```

Again, a small impact.
Now, if the impact of this is "small enough" then you can run this *many times* each day (or night) moving the "window" slightly, each time.
By the time you've caught up to where you need to be (one year), then you have a well-practiced process that just needs to be run *daily*, thereafter.